# Formatting text boxes in Google forms

Tags: google-forms

I am using Google forms "Get Pre-filled linked" and fill out some text boxes automatically. Here is an example text-box filled out with with "pre-filled link": 
[image]

Is there a way to format the text inside the textbox? For example: 
 - Have new lines in the text box. 
 - Make some parts of it bold.

An example desired output with new lines (which I have added manually; not sure how make parts of text bold): 
 [image]

Thoughts on how to format text for Google forms?

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for the same functionality and all I can find on the google forums is "it doesn't support that."

My workaround is this:  Create the formatted text in a google doc then take a screen grab with the Snippet tool (or SnagIt or whatever your favorite screen grabber is).

Save the image to your drive then add it to the form.

This seems like a ridiculous thing to have to do, but it does work.

Comment: Good hack, but in my case, the content is not static.